# How hangfire start schedule job with Corn Expression

Tags: c#, cron, owin, hangfire

The testing code is to check how many times the Cron.Minutely schedule jobs have been run in the background after 5 seconds and 1 mins later check again.

My question is once the jobs have been scheduled, it runs straightaway or wait till the time is say 12:01:00? Does that mean when jobs scheduled on 23:59:30 and 23:59:57 would run different times. for example: 2 simple jobs
   23:59:30             23:59:57
5s   0                      2
1min 2                      4